# Can't change input's border color in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I've tried changing the stroke color in the mat input every way I can find, but the color is still purple. Font's color changed perfectly but border line's doesn't. What can I do with this?

Here is html:

```
<div class="login-page">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <div id="form">
        <form [formGroup]="loginForm">
            <div class="justify-content-center">
                <mat-form-field class="mffield" appearance="outline">
                    <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
                    <input matInput formControlName="username">
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            
            <div class="justify-content-center">
                <mat-form-field class="mffield" appearance="outline">
                    <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
                    <input type="password" matInput formControlName="password">
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>

            <div id="controls" class="row">
                <button style="width: 20%;" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" (click)="submit()" mat-flat-button color="primary">
                    Login
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is css:

```
...
  
.mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) .mdc-notched-outline__leading,
.mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) .mdc-notched-outline__notch,
.mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
  border-color: red !important;
}

.mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled).mdc-text-field--focused .mdc-notched-outline__leading,
.mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled).mdc-text-field--focused .mdc-notched-outline__notch,
.mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled).mdc-text-field--focused .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
  border-color: red !important;
}

.mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled):not(.mdc-text-field--focused):hover .mdc-notched-outline .mdc-notched-outline__leading,
.mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled):not(.mdc-text-field--focused):hover .mdc-notched-outline .mdc-notched-outline__notch,
.mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled):not(.mdc-text-field--focused):hover .mdc-notched-outline .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
  border-color: red !important;
}
```

I tried this code

```
.mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) .mdc-notched-outline__leading,
.mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) .mdc-notched-outline__notch,
.mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled) .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
  border-color: red !important;
}

.mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled).mdc-text-field--focused .mdc-notched-outline__leading,
.mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled).mdc-text-field--focused .mdc-notched-outline__notch,
.mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled).mdc-text-field--focused .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
  border-color: red !important;
}

.mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled):not(.mdc-text-field--focused):hover .mdc-notched-outline .mdc-notched-outline__leading,
.mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled):not(.mdc-text-field--focused):hover .mdc-notched-outline .mdc-notched-outline__notch,
.mdc-text-field--outlined:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled):not(.mdc-text-field--focused):hover .mdc-notched-outline .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
  border-color: red !important;
}
```

And something like this:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
  color: white;
}
```

But this does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular Material is pretty good with the css variables.  In this case you probably want **--mdc-outlined-text-field-outline-color** which is the source of the outline color for text fields.

In the example below the outline color is set to red using the [style property binding syntax](https://angular.dev/guide/templates/class-binding#binding-to-a-single-style).

```
<mat-form-field class="mffield" appearance="outline"
  [style.--mdc-outlined-text-field-outline-color]="'red'">
  <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
  <input matInput formControlName="username">
</mat-form-field>
```

You should also be able to do this in css.  I noticed the class named *mffield* on your form fields.  You can simply set the property value in a rule for that class.

```
.mffield {
  --mdc-outlined-text-field-outline-color: red;
}
```